# Replace 0 with -9

Tags: search, str-replace

My data contain 0 which I want to remove with -9, but not those data point which are like 220 or 120. How to do it? For example data are like:
  M1  M2  M3  M4
  120  0  125  0
  0  123  123  0
  123  0  0  123

to

M1  M2  M3  M4
  120  -9  125  -9
  -9 123  123  -9
  123  -9  -9  123

Comment: Use regex to replace ` 0 ` with ` -9 `. If you post a question, also explain in what language.

Comment: Can you be more clear? Also, what language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You would search for `" 0 "` and replace with `" -9 "`

Comment: Note: The spaces protect from numbers over a single digit (assuming this is a string).